# The following sentences are selected from "Fright Night" movie.what do the bold sentences mean?

Tags: meaning

[Charley] Doris, do you want some help with the trash?

[Doris] Oh, **I got it**. Thanks.

[Doris] All right. Good to see you, **Char-Char.You're getting big.**

Comment: Please do not repost a question which has been [closed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/74810/32); it just wastes everybody's time.

Comment: @StoneyB: This is a different question. Why the other one was closed is kind of a mystery. The guy's watching a show and has a problem understanding some of the lines. This site is supposed to help those who wish to learn English, correct? Isn't that what the site's title actually _means_? What am I missing?

Comment: @Ricky: In this particular case, the questions do not appear to be duplicates. But in general, closing (as duplicates, especially, but even for other reasons) is not in opposition to our mission of helping learners in the aggregate. If a question is not in shape for us to answer well, leaving it open does not help anyone (except possibly the original poster), but rather causes harm by spreading confusion and wasting time. If a question has already been answered (or if someone is just reposting the same question to try to get more attention), pointing all attention at that question helps also.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: Good points, all. However, I still don't understand why the other question was closed (after garnering two answers), nor why anyone should insist on closing this one. What's wrong with it?

Comment: There is some [advice in the help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for asking good questions. My objection to this question would be that you don't explain what's confusing you when you try to understand it. If we understood what you were thinking a little better we could write an answer that might help you understand more than just those two sentences and might help someone else with a similar question. I will vote to leave it open, but it would be great so see a little more context than "what does this mean?"

Comment: My apologies to everyone, including OP. The question I linked is NOT a duplicate, and I would retract it if I could. ... But there's something wonky going on, because I swear I've seen this very question, with "Char-Char", and not just now but some hours ago ...

Comment: @Ricky: Bingo (Thank you, Google). The question **was** posted yesterday ([here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/74805/what-does-you-are-getting-big-mean) for those who can read it), closed for more detail by Nathan Tuggy, ColleenV, StoneyB, Nihilist_Frost, and Jim, and deleted by OP just before reposting here. -- Like I said, just wasting everybody's time instead of doing what Nathan asked yesterday and editing to provide the information we need.

Comment: @StoneyB: What kind of information do you have in mind? I'm sorry if I'm being stupid or anything: I'm not doing it to spite you. I just don't understand. The OP isn't trying to spite anyone either, I don't think. He's just watching a movie (a contemptibly silly one, I admit) and trying to understand the lines. It does get pretty frustrating sometimes (I watched a bunch of old French movies not too long ago, so I think I know how the guy feels, it _is_ annoying when something as ridiculously simple as "You're getting big" suddenly becomes an insurmountable obstacle.

Comment: @Ricky It seems unreasonable at first glance, but how useful would the site be if it was just a long list of "What does this specific sentence mean" questions? The idea is to create a reference that learners can use, not to help one specific person understand one specific movie. I can see how this question could be about more than that but the way it's currently written, it isn't helpful to anyone that isn't watching that movie.

Comment: @ColleenV: What kind of context? Would you have the OP describe the scene? Provide the characters' respective blood types? Elucidate the Shakesperean strain in "with the trash"? Sheesh.

Comment: @Ricky Not "context of the source material" - context of why the asker is having trouble understanding it and what they did to try to answer their question before asking it. Related discussion on meta [Don't feed the Bears](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1236/9161).

Comment: @ColleenV: "The idea is to create a reference that learners can use" The movie isn't exactly a masterpiece of linguistic originality. "I got it," "Char-Char," and "You're getting big" are astoundingly common idiomatic phrases that many learners could benefit from knowing ... uh ... I don't know. I'd much prefer explaining Shakespeare, Sheridan and Shaw, but some people don't even know who those guys are and _still_ wish to speak and understand English. You and I may not like it, but that's just how some people _are_.

Comment: @ColleenV: Pardon me if I come across as rude - I'm not trying to be rude -  Have you ever tried learning a new language as a grownup or a semi-grown up? How is someone barely familiar with the language is supposed to "try to answer" a question about a specific idiom? There's very little logic to idioms. And some people aren't logical, and it isn't their fault. "You're getting big" can mean more than just one thing - how's the OP supposed to know which? Etc, etc.

Comment: @Ricky You've seen the movie, so you can answer this. I haven't; so I don't know whether "I got it" means "I did that already" or "I'm handling it fine without help", and I don't know whether "You're getting big" is a middle-aged woman remarking on the maturation of a young man she knew when he was small or a critical peer remarking on Char-Char's increasing obesity. OP's got the context, and I don't think it's unreasonable to ask them to provide it -- which is what Nathan did when the question was first posted.

Comment: @Ricky I understand you're not being rude, and I'm not trying to dismiss how difficult learning English is, or to throw cold water on your desire to help folks. The site has 21 thousand questions - if we don't refine the quality of questions, it becomes impossible for learners to find answers because of all the noise. It is because English is difficult that we need to make sure the questions we spend our time answering are going to be useful to others and not just obscure relevant results when a learner searches for "I got it".

Comment: @StoneyB: I haven't seen the movie, nor do I have the slightest urge to fill in that particular blank in my knowledge. Ill-informed movies for misguided teenagers aren't my cup of tea. I can sort of deduce the meaning from the lines the OP provided, and I daresay so can you.

Comment: @ColleenV: Hey, I'm all for quality, and if you ask me, two-thirds of the questions (and answers) on this site should be deleted. But, but ... _this_ question isn't one of those. I don't see how a learner could tackle the witty exchange between Hamlet and Ophelia unless they grasp what "I got it" and "You're getting big" mean _first_. I'm not saying it's impossible: just very, very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it** means "I can do it without anyone's help; I have it all under control."

**Char-Char** is a nickname for Charles (Charley) as well as a term of endearment. (As in Ray-Ray (for Raymond or Rachel), Lulu (for Louise), Jojo (for Joseph or Josephine) or Jay-Jay for Jason).

**You're getting big** means "You're growing fast, you're almost a grownup, wow."